# What happens with my navigation and Slider in Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am working on my own website: www.heike-waltz.de

I was used to use conditional comments for IE in the past. But as this is not possible anymore for IE10 I don't know how to solve my problem.

My navigation works fine on all browsers expect IE. The bottom line is not on the correct spot if you hover. It sits about 1px above the black " border-bottom-line".

Also my slider is not working in IE. It is a javascript I added.....

I really don't know what to do:)

Any idea?

Would be very much appreciated.

Cheers,
Heike

Comment: a) Post a [mcve] in your question please and b) why do you care about IE10? It's seven years old and will reach its end of life in January 2020

Answer (score 0):

I checked your website in IE, in console there's a syntax error and it points to the [arrow function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLGN7.png) line. Arrow function is [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility) in IE. So you should translate it to ES5 syntax then it can run in IE:

```
pause = function pause() {
    clearInterval(myTimer);
};

resume = function resume() {
     clearInterval(myTimer);
     myTimer = setInterval(function () {
         plusSlides(slideIndex);
     }, 5000);
};
```

Besides, you could use media queries to load IE specific CSS. You could try to add the following code in stylesheet to adjust the bottom line position in IE:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) { /*media query to detect IE*/ 
    #desktop-nav > ul > li > a {
        color: black;
        position: relative;
        width: auto;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: color 0.5s linear;
        padding: 10px 0 11px 0;
    }
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    .active-link a {
        color: #40c2c2 !important;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #40c2c2;
        padding: 10px 0 10px 0 !important;
    }
}
```